# List like iphone and HTC hero phone app

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create a list like iphone list and HTC hero phone app.

So how can i do that because I tried it with default ListView but I can not make two list in a single layout and ScrollView does not work on it.

So can any body help me about this matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two listviews in the same layout if you don't use ListActivity and do some of the work ListActivty does for you yourself. I can't understand what kind of result you want to get but I would advise against having two lists in a single layout. It is very confusing for the user because he will have to scrollable parts on one screen. Maybe if you provide more detail about how you want your app to look like we can give you a more specific answer.